# Display DD/MM/YYYY PHP echo from Database

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone knows how to pull and display the date a member sign up through your website using phpmyadmin following the format: DD/MM/YYYY example: `<?php echo $row->date; ?>` maybe? I am assuming something similar to this will work: `echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");` but would be more the date a member joined not the current date.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: How is the date stored in the database? is it using unixtimestamp or it is a date field?

Comment: I also don't have a table where members can submit the date they joined but I am using WordPress in case that is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

if $row->date is some date/time string, one way would be to use strtotime.

```
$time = strtotime($row->date);
//then use the date function as you need
$date = date('d/m/Y', $time);
echo $date;
```

if you want an sql query

SELECT date(date,%d/%m/%Y) FROM tbl_name

Comment: Here is how I have it on my code:  `<li style="margin-left: 67px;font-family: Myriad Pro Bold ! important;"><b style="margin-right: 20px;">Member Since:</b> <?php echo goes here; ?></li>` I also don't have a table where members can submit the date they joined but I am using WordPress in case that is very helpful.

Comment: can you show the while loop around the li?

Comment: I wouldn't use `strtotime` without knowing what format the date string is in.

Comment: I agree but that info is not provided here. In most cases though, db will store date in datetime so it should work.

Comment: Yes James that's what I am trying to figure out. When a member sign up through my website I am sure WP stores the date somewhere. So I am trying to find how how to display that date. Thanks a lot

Comment: john, again, can you display the entire loop?

Comment: What do you mean  by the entire loop? My code is scattered and is in the same file as css so the line I have submitted is what I am interested in Thanks again for all you do